# Varying the start and end date of openssl self-signed certificates

Tags: openssl

I have these three statements to generate a self-signed cert with a root certificate that I have.

```
openssl genrsa -out domain.org.key
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout domain.org.key -subj "/C=CN/ST=GD/L=SZ/O=Acme, Inc./CN=*.domain.org" -out domain.org.csr
openssl x509 -req -extfile <(printf "subjectAltName=DNS:domain.org,DNS:www.domain.org") -days 1 -in domain.org.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out domain.org.crt
```

However, over here the validity periods can be changed for only a single day. Does anyone know if there is an argument I could add to these that would let me vary the start date and the end date to the granularity of seconds, or minutes. For testing purposes, I need to create several certificates whose validity periods vary for just a few minutes. I've looked at other answers, and they suggest using the `ca` command:

```
openssl ca -config /path/to/myca.conf -in req.csr -out ourdomain.pem \
-startdate 0801010000Z -enddate 1001010000Z
```

But I am not sure how to combine the two since the second command only seems to be generating a key for the domain. Could anyone help combining the two commands, and or changing cert times some other way that doesn't involve changing my system time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

openssl command line does not provide command line options to set the start and end dates for the "x509 -req" option.

If you really need to do this, you can modify the openssl source to do what you want.

In the app\req.c you need to modify the "set_cert_times" call:

```
    if (days == 0) {
        /* set default days if it's not specified */
        days = 30;
    }
    if (!set_cert_times(x509ss, NULL, NULL, days))
        goto end;

int set_cert_times(X509 *x, const char *startdate, const char *enddate,
                   int days)
```

If you provide a startdate and enddate it will override the days parameter soyou can do this:

```
if (!set_cert_times(x509ss, "0801010000Z", "1001010000Z", days))
    goto end;
```

That will hardcode the start and end dates or with a little bit more work you can add support for the -startdate and -enddate parameters to the x509 -req processing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Would I have to change the code, and then recompile openssl to use it again? Also, is there a way to do this so that I can give the start and end times as argument?

Comment: yes and yes.  if you look into the req.c file you can see the argument processing for the -req option and you should be able to add support for those arguments easily enough.  I am assuming you understand C language.

Comment: I can read `C` and understand it, but am not very good at it. I am guessing that if I add a new argument inside `req_options` and `OPTION_choice` (linked below), and then extract that value in the switch case that starts at line `249` over [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/req.c#L84), and then make changes to `set_cert_times`, it should work?

Comment: It should do.  You can copy the startdate / enddate option processing lines from apps\ca.cpp, that should make it easier for you.

Comment: Oooh, nice, thanks for pointing that out! I'll see how it goes, will post it here.